# How to buy BTC for all available BUSD on Binance with API call?

Tags: linux, binance

I would like to buy `BTC` for all available `BUSD` on Binance with API call.

For example if I have 49 BUSD, I want to convert all of them immediately to `BTC` for whatever is the current price.

I think I have to use `MARKET` type to do it.

It works with this query, but in this case I have to define the amount of `BUSD`.

```
symbol=BTCBUSD&side=BUY&type=MARKET&quantity=49&timestamp=123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `quoteOrderQty` param instead of `quantity`.

The `quoteOrderQty` allows you to specify the quantity of the quote asset. So if you have a `BTCBUSD` symbol, the `quoteOrderQty` is amount of `BUSD`.

Docs: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#new-order-trade

---

*Note: Don't forget to account for fees. So if you have exactly 49 BUSD, an order for 49 BUSD will fail, because you wouldn't be able to cover the fees.*